# Finding the weighted median in an unsorted array in linear time

Tags: algorithm

This is from the practice problem in one of coursera's Algorithms courses; I've been stuck for a couple of weeks.

The problem is this:

`Given an array of n distinct unsorted elements x1, x2, ..., xn ε X with positive weights w1, w2, ..., wn ε W, a weighted median is an element xk for which the total weight of all elements with values less than xk is at most (total weight)/2 and also the total weight of elements with values larger than xk is at most (total weight)/2. Observe that there are at most two weighted. Show how to compute all weighted medians in O(n) worst time`

The course mostly covered divide and conquer algorithms, so I think the key to get started on this would be to identify which of the algorithms covered can be used for this problem.

One of the algorithms covered was the `RSelect` algorithm in the form `RSelect(array X, length n, order statistic i)` which for a weighted median could be written as `RSelect(array X, weights W, length n, order statistic i)`. My issue with this approach is that it assumes I know the median value ahead of time, which seems unlikely. There's also the issue that the pivot is chosen uniformly at random, which I don't imagine is likely to work with weights without computing every weight for every entry.

Next is the `DSelect` algorithms, where using a median of medians approach a pivot may be computed without randomization so we can compute a proper median. This seems like the approach that could work, where I have trouble is that it also assumes that I know ahead of time the value I'm looking for.

`DSelect(array A, length n, order statistic i)` for an unweighted array

`DSelect(array A, weights W, length n, order statistic i)` for a weighted array

Am I overthinking this? Should I use `DSelect` assuming that I know the value of `(total weight) / 2` ahead of time? I guess even if I compute it it would add only linear time to the running time. But then it would be no different from precomputing a weighted array (`combine A, W into Q where qi = xi*wi`) and transforming this back to an unweighted array problem where I can use `RSelect` (plus some accounting for cases where there are two medians)

I've found https://archive.org/details/lineartimealgori00blei/page/n3 and https://blog.nelsonliu.me/2016/07/05/gsoc-week-6-efficient-calculation-of-weighted-medians/ which describe this problem, but their approach doesn't seem to be something covered in the course (and I'm not familiar with heaps/heapsort)

Comment: Are you saying that the median on the vector obtained by scalar product of X and W is at the same index as weighted median in the original problem? For example, in `X=[5, 10, 7]` and `W=[2, 2, 3]`, the weighted median is 7, but median of `X*W=[10, 20, 21]` is 20.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with a simple variant of quickselect:

1. Calculate the sum of all weights and divide by 2 to get the target sum
2. Choose a pivot and partition the array into larger and smaller elements
3. Sum the weights in the smaller partition, and subtract from the total to get the sum in the other partition
4. go back to 2 to process the appropriate partition with the appropriate target sum

Just like normal quickselect, this becomes linear in the worst case if you use the (normal, unweighted) median-of-medians approach to choose a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

This average performance can be achieved with [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

The randomly chosen pivot can be chosen - with weighting - with the [Reservoir Sampling Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reservoir-sampling/).  You are correct that it is `O(n)` to find the first pivot, but the size of the lists that you're working with will follow a geometric series, so the total cost of finding pivots will still work out to be only `O(n)`.